# Modify directive controller variable from link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, timeout, angularjs-scope

I've created a plunker with my code wrapped, but for some reason the `ng-click` won't work in there.
Well, hope this is enough to show my problem. http://plnkr.co/edit/ILbz7tMLpOgXyO0Dx6su?p=preview

So I'm trying to create my own simple `MessageService` which is a service that holds a message for a next `$state` (using ui-router).

I've created a little directive which I've included in my plunker as well.
This directive is showing the message on the next route, but for some reason (which I don't know) it wont trigger the `$timeout` function, where I set the `scope.feedback` to null.

As you can see in my plunker, I've got a `ng-show="feedback"` on the directive template, and I fill this within the directive controller with the `MessageService.get()` for retrieving the message. The in my link function I want to set it to null, to hide it after a period of time.

**Template:**

```
<div ng-show="feedback" class="feedback">
  <div class="alert feedback-message alert-success">{{feedback}}</div>
</div>
```

**Controller function:**

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
   $scope.feedback = MessageService.get();
});
```

**Link function:**

```
if (scope.feedback != null) {
   if (scope.feedback.type == 'success') {
      scope.typeClass = 'alert-success';
   } else if (scope.feedback.type == 'error') {
      scope.typeClass = 'alert-danger';
   }

   $timeout(function () {
      scope.feedback = null;
   }, 1500)
}
```

If you need more information, let me know.

Comment: Please post relevant code directly in the question. While external demos are very helpful, your question should be self contained without having to leave this site

Comment: your button isn't within the scope of `MainController`. It is outside of `ui-view`

Comment: @charlietfl I've added code and also updated my plunker. Lol yea, really dumb... haha. Demo is working as local now, hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link` function of the directive doesn't just automatically execute periodically, it has no idea when the `statechangeSuccess` event has happened as well. It will just run only when the directive renders (compiled). Just hide it on `$stateChangeSuccess` itself.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
    $scope.feedback = MessageService.get();
     $timeout(function () {
        $scope.feedback = null;
    }, 1500)
});
```

Or just add a method on the controller (or you could just add it on the scope as well)

```
var _this = this;
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
    $scope.feedback = MessageService.get();
    $timeout(_this.hideFeedBack, 1500); //Invoke it here
});

_this.hideFeedBack = function(){
    $scope.feedback = null;
 }
```

and also access it in the link function using the 4th argument which gives the controller instance.

```
 link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RhfV93XJgac5mTkJXhqb?p=preview)**

Comment: I've moved it into my controller, but it looks like it doesn't wait for the `$timeout`.  I've set the timeout to 2500 and it feels like  it dissapears after 0.5 sec. Well it's working now though.

Comment: Sure. Did you see my demo? i think you might be executing the function instead of setting the reference. Can you show me a demo if you are seeing any issues?